# How do I make multicolor text in the same line in word using Apache PO in JavaI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I need to generate a word document using Apache POI that has multiple colors of text in one single line and then ends with a horizontal line break. Like in the example bellow:

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58h7k.png)

I tried to use `mainText.setBorderBetween(Borders.BASIC_THIN_LINES);` to get a horizontal line and it worked but the horizontal line is pushed all the way down and not centered properly. I tried using:

`mainTextRun.setColor("FFA500");`
`mainTextRun.setText("text 1");`
`mainTextRun.setColor("008000");`
`mainTextRun.setText("text 2");`
`mainTextRun.setColor("0000FF");`
`mainTextRun.setText("text 3");`

But it did not produce the desired text as it kept skipping lines as seen here:

[Pain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfNMg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `mainText` is a `XWPFParagraph` and  your `mainTextRun` are multiple `XWPFRun` created in that `XWPFParagraph`. Then the following small [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) works and produces the Word document shown below.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordParagraphBorderAndColoredTextRuns {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph mainText = document.createParagraph();
  mainText.setBorderBottom(Borders.BASIC_THIN_LINES);
  
  XWPFRun mainTextRun = mainText.createRun(); 
  mainTextRun.setColor("FFA500"); mainTextRun.setText("text 1 "); 
  mainTextRun = mainText.createRun();
  mainTextRun.setColor("008000"); mainTextRun.setText("text 2 "); 
  mainTextRun = mainText.createRun();
  mainTextRun.setColor("0000FF"); mainTextRun.setText("text 3 ");

  mainText = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordParagraphBorderAndColoredTextRuns.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do. I was unawere that it was possible to create multiple instances of the XWPFRun objects, and it somehow did not occur to me to try. As a result I kept tying to acomplish my goal by using multiple paragraphs. I am sorry for not being clear enough in my initial post, its my first question and I was so frustrated by multiple hours of failure that I didn't think straight. Thanks you for answering despite that, you have no idea how much this has helped me.